# Rewriting redirects to include the port used to access the service

Tags: http, redirect, nginx

I have a setup like this:

[image]

A user working with my Vagrant development environment accesses `localhost:8080` on their host machine, which is forwarded into Vagrant to NGINX running at `localhost:80` on the guest. Some requests are forwarded into my application server running at `localhost:8080` on the guest, and some are static files served from NGINX.

A weird thing happens when I access my site. I have a login page which redirects on success, and the URL is rewritten from `http://localhost:8080/login` to `http://localhost:80/login`.

Here's my NGINX configuration for the site:

```
upstream appserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

upstream production {
    server www.mysite.com:443;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/project.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project.error.log;

    index /index;

    location ~ ^(/js/testpage.js) {
        alias   /vagrant/artifacts/www/js/testpage.js;
    }

    location ~ ^(/test/js/app.js) {
        alias   /vagrant/test/js/app.js;
    }

    location ~ /test/js/app_router.js {
        alias   /vagrant/test/js/app_router.js;
    }

    location ~ /test/js/app_layout_controller.js {
        alias   /vagrant/test/js/app_layout_controller.js;
    }

    location ~ /test/js/apps/navbar/sections/layout/navbar_layout_controller.js {
        alias   /vagrant/test/js/apps/navbar/sections/layout/navbar_layout_controller.js;
    }

    location ~ /test/js/apps/navbar/sections/navbar/navbar_options_view.js {
        alias   /vagrant/test/js/apps/navbar/sections/navbar/navbar_options_view.js;
    }

    location ~ /test/js/apps/navbar/sections/navbar_all_views.js {
        alias   /vagrant/test/js/apps/navbar/sections/navbar_all_views.js;
    }

    location ~ ^/test/js/apps/(.*/testpage_.*\.js)$ {
        alias   /vagrant/test/js/apps/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/test/js/(.*)$ {
        alias /vagrant/js/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/build/js/(.*)$ {
        alias /vagrant/artifacts/www/js/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/build/css/(.*)$ {
        alias /vagrant/artifacts/www/css/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*main.*)\.[@\-_\/\d\w]+\.(js|css)$ {
        alias /vagrant/$1.$2;
    }

    location ~ ^/(css|js|fonts|favicon.ico) {
        root   /vagrant;
    }

    location ~ ^/receipts/js/(.*)$ {
        alias /vagrant/receipts/js/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/bower_components/(.*)$ {
        alias /vagrant/bower_components/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/login-promo/ {
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass https://production;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ ^/(admin|login|logout|index|build|testpage|receipts|open|reset|resetpage|privacy|change|activeUser|personPrivacyAcceptances) {
        access_log off;

        proxy_pass http://appserver;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where the redirect is actually coming from, it could be coming from the app server backend or from the front end JavaScript. Is there a way that I can make sure that all redirects take the port used by the accessing client?

---

Update: Simply adding a `<a href="/login">login</a>` link to the root page and trying to navigate with that link redirects me to `http://localhost:80/login` rather than `http://localhost:8080/login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by doing redirects wrong in application code.

If you have a similar architecture as above and are experiencing the problem, it's likely that the reason you're experiencing the problem is because of a naive attempt at redirecting without accounting for the `Host` header.

Your application behind nginx sees a request like this:

```
GET /path/to/resource
Host: virtualinstance:8888
```

Unfortunately, when it constructs the redirect, it does something dumb and reconstructs the redirect without taking into account the `Host` header,  instead opting for the host and port which it knows it is using. The code that was breaking my redirect looked something like this:

```
return redirect("http://" + getHostName() + "/" + getPath())
```

First, it's bad that it hardcodes the protocol, but worse yet that it uses a method which gets the host name without regard for the port. This would return a redirect to `http://localhost/path`, rather than `http://localhost:8888/path`.

Developers, this is why you should always use the `Host` header as a source for your redirect:

```
return redirect("%s://%s/%s" % (getProtocol(), getHeader("Host"), 
    getPath())
```

This makes a sane redirect, using the original protocol, full text from `Host`, and the path.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an undesired side-effect of fowarding the guest's nginx port to a different one on the host.

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Desactivating the proxy redirection in the last location block should do the trick:

```
proxy_redirect off;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely happening due to `port_in_redirect` being `on` by default. See: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#port_in_redirect

Disabling that would likely stop some of the confusion as to why the port is being applied.

From there, it's a simple as setting the appropriate `host_port` or `remote_port` in your proxy pass redirects, as necessary. By looking at your config, it seems you are comfortable using the core module variables, it would be quite simple to include those variables.

See:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24remote_port
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24server_port